# How would I integrate torrent downloading in an android app?

Tags: android, libraries, torrent

I am interested in creating an Android app that when you are using the browser app or google chrome, and you click "Get this torrent" on a torrent downloading site, it opens the app and proceeds to download. With that said, I have a few questions.

1. Are there certain libraries I need?
2. How do you use magnet links in an app?
3. How do I make it so my app opens when I click "Get this torrent"? (clicking on the magnet link)

I apologize if I sound clueless, but I've looked all over the web for an answer but nobody seems to know. I've done a lot of research, and I don't expect anyone to do the work for me. Can you at least point me in the right direction? Oh, and before people go off on me for "condoning piracy", I'm curious and trying to learn, not destroy the universe.

Comment: Could I amend this question?

For myself, I am looking for a 3rd-party library (free if possible) to incorporate into my c#/Xamarin project where I can store and transmit magnet links between my app and the cloud, and the app itself requests the data via torrent network.

The magnet links are just the 'address' for the data.

There is a javascript library that does this that does seem to work on mobile browsers - webtorrent.js

Answer (score 1):

This is actually already built into android itself. By using the Intent class, you can throw a request to android, who runs it through intent filters to see if there's a matching application.

Something like this happens underwater

```
Intent torrentIntent = new Intent(Intent.SOME_TORRENT_FILTER_SPECIFIC_VALUE);
torrentIntent.setData(Uri.parse(yourtorrentfilehere));
activity.startActivity(torrentIntent);
```

By doing this your browser is throwing out the intent to any possible application that can handle it. If there are multiple, it shows a choosing dialog. If there are none, the filetype can't be opened.

I think your main issue will be that you don't actually have access to the browser code so you can't change the event being launched. You'll have to create your own filter for both torrent files and magnet links being opened, then catch them and redirect them to a torrent application you have running.

By the way Pro Android 4 is a great resource for stuff like this, even if it is a bit generic.